# Keyboard lockup when typing <ctrl><shift> and random characters

Tags: command-line, keyboard

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 with a terminal window.  Because I type fairly quickly I sometimes use ctrl-u to wipe out my partially entered line which works great.  Once my partially typed line is wiped out, I am back at my command prompt and am ready to enter a command.

But sometimes I accidently press ctrl-shift-u and then immediately start typing (thinking I am at the command prompt again).  Instead of wiping out the line, the characters I type are underlined and sometimes get converted into hex characters, or sometimes if I type too many characters when it is in this mode, my keyboard completely locks up.  Even if I open an new terminal window I still can't type.  The only solution is a reboot.

What am I activating when I type ctrl-shift-u followed by other characters?  And is there a way for me to configure this feature off so I don't lock myself up?

(Perhaps I should type more carefully so I don't accidently hit ctrl-shift)

Thanks for your help,
Robert

Comment: I don't know why it is slowing your system, but you are activating unicode input.

Answer (score 1):

I just found out that IBus was activating, and it substitutes Unicode characters.  I guess pressing more than 4 characters locks up keyboard input.

I found out how to disable IBus completely.  I went to the Ubuntu system settings, selected **Language Support**.  Under **Keyboard input method system** I changed *IBus* to *none*, and my <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>U</kbd> lockup problems are now gone.

Thank you Adonis for directing me to the solution.